# The set of non-smooth points of a convex function is (m - 1)-rectifiable

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

I am looking for a reference to the following result.

> Let $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R$ be a convex function.
>   Then $f$ is differentiable at all points of outside of a countable union of $(m-1)$-rectifiable sets.

**Comments:**

- $n$-rectifiable set is an image of Lipschitz map from bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$
- I checked Federer's *"Geometric Measure Theory"*, but I might miss the right place.
- **Extract from the Greg's answer** *(for those who are lazy to read the paper):* In [this paper](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/101616), it is given a complete characterization of subsets of nondifferatiable points of a convex function. Namely, it is proved that $A$ is a such a set if and only if it can be covered by countably many graphs of DC-functions. ("DC-function" = "Difference of Convex functions".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paper [On the differentiation of convex functions in finite and infinite dimensional spaces](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/101616) by Zajíček primarily deals with the general question in Banach space, but it looks like it has a summary of the situation (as of 1979) that tells you everything that you might want  to know.  It has references to closer papers by Anderson-Klee and Besicovitch.

I just Googled around and eventually got to this paper.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still interested in the questions, but I included an easy to read proof of Zajíček's result in the paper:

P. Hajłasz, On an old theorem of Erdős about ambiguous locus. Colloquium Math. 168 (2022), 249–256.

You can download the paper from my website or from arXiv.